# MICR symbols rendering small on output device after migrated to Windows server 2016 from WIndows server 2008 on VB.net code

Tags: vb.net

The Code had been worked on Windows 2008 server but we migrated to windows 2016 server then the symbols producing small on out device.we have hardcoded MICR symbols in the program and I tried different font style, previously we had "Arial MS Unicode" later changed to "Courier New" nothing worked to produce correct symbols. could you please check and help me to sort out the issue?

Function convertFrontIRD(chkImgBytes() As Byte) As Image
Dim irdWidth As Integer, irdHeight As Integer, fontSize As Integer, micrFontSize As Integer, micrChrFontSize As Integer, irdtxtFontSize As Integer

```
    fontSize = 10
    micrFontSize = 10
    micrChrFontSize = micrFontSize + 2
    irdtxtFontSize = fontSize - 1

    irdWidth = 8.5 * ppi      ' ( Assuming Letter paper size, 8.5 inch X 300 pixes/inch PPI)
    irdHeight = CInt((11 / 3) * ppi)    ' ( Assuming Letter paper size, 11 inch X 300 pixes/inch PPI) and each page would have 3 IRD pages
    Dim irdImg = New Bitmap(irdWidth, irdHeight)
    irdImg.SetResolution(ppi, ppi)
    Dim irdGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(irdImg)
    irdGraphics.Clear(Color.White)

    Dim strText As String, stringSize As New SizeF, strFont As Font, textFormat As New System.Drawing.StringFormat
    Dim yGap As Int16, xGap As Int16

    yGap = 2 : xGap = 5

    Dim lbWidth As Integer, lbHeight As Integer, boxX As Integer, boxY As Integer, boxX1 As Integer, boxY1 As Integer

    ''''       Left Window        
    lbWidth = 1.88 * ppi : lbHeight = 2.85 * ppi : boxX = 0 : boxY = 10 * yGap : boxX1 = lbWidth : boxY1 = 0
    strFont = New Font("OCR-A Hanna", fontSize)
    textFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    textFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center

    'Bank RT
    strText = "*" & bankRt & "*"
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxY1 = boxY + stringSize.Height
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1), textFormat)

    'Business Date
    strText = Format(Today, "MM/dd/yyyy")
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxY = boxY1 + yGap
    boxY1 = boxY + stringSize.Height
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1), textFormat)

    'Application seq Number
    strText = aeSeq
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxY = boxY1 + yGap
    boxY1 = boxY + stringSize.Height
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1), textFormat)

    'IRD Text
    strFont = New Font("Courier New", irdtxtFontSize)
    textFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
    textFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near

    strText = "This is a LEGAL COPY of your"
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxY = boxY1 + 2 * stringSize.Height
    boxY1 = boxY + stringSize.Height
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1), textFormat)


    'IRD Text
    strText = "check. You can use it the same"
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxY = boxY1 + yGap
    boxY1 = boxY + stringSize.Height
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1), textFormat)

    'IRD Text
    strText = "way you would use the original"
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxY = boxY1 + yGap
    boxY1 = boxY + stringSize.Height
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1), textFormat)

    'IRD Text
    strText = "check."
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxY = boxY1 + yGap
    boxY1 = boxY + stringSize.Height
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1), textFormat)

    strFont = New Font("OCR-A Hanna", fontSize)
    textFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
    textFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near

    If Trim(resCode) <> "" Then
        strText = "RETURN REASON - " & resCode
        stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
        boxY = boxY1 + 2 * stringSize.Height
        boxY1 = boxY + stringSize.Height
        irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1), textFormat)

        If Trim(resDesc) <> "" Then
            strText = resDesc
            stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
            boxY = boxY1 + yGap
            boxY1 = boxY + stringSize.Height
            irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1), textFormat)
        End If
    End If


    ' Middle Vertical Text        
    Dim mbWidth As Integer, mbHeight As Integer
    mbHeight = 0.37 * ppi : mbWidth = 2.6 * ppi : boxX = lbWidth + xGap : boxY = yGap : boxX1 = boxX + mbHeight : boxY1 = boxY + mbWidth
    strFont = New Font("OCR-A Hanna ", fontSize)
    textFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    textFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center

    strText = "[" & bankRt & "] " & depDate & vbNewLine & hsSeq
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    'textFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical
    irdGraphics.TranslateTransform(boxX1, boxY1)
    irdGraphics.RotateTransform(-90)
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX / 1.5, -stringSize.Height / 2, 0, 0), textFormat)
    irdGraphics.ResetTransform()


    'Top Text
    Dim tWidth As Integer, tHeight As Integer
    tWidth = 5 * ppi : tHeight = 0.33 * ppi
    If Trim(resDesc) <> "" Then
        boxX = lbWidth + xGap + mbHeight + xGap : boxY = yGap : boxX1 = boxX + tWidth : boxY1 = tHeight
        textFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
        textFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
        irdGraphics.DrawString(resDesc, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1), textFormat)
    End If

    ' Check Image
    Dim chkImage As Image
    Dim cImgWidth As Integer, cImgHeight As Integer
    cImgWidth = 5.75 * ppi : cImgHeight = 2.42 * ppi : boxX = lbWidth + xGap + mbHeight + xGap : boxY = tHeight + yGap : boxX1 = boxX + cImgWidth : boxY1 = boxY + cImgHeight
    chkImage = Bitmap.FromStream(New IO.MemoryStream(chkImgBytes))

    If (chkImage.Width / chkImage.Height) * cImgHeight < cImgWidth Then cImgWidth = (chkImage.Width / chkImage.Height) * cImgHeight
    irdGraphics.DrawImage(chkImage, boxX, boxY, cImgWidth, cImgHeight)
    'irdGraphics.DrawImage(chkImage, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1))

    'Bottom Text        
    Dim bbWidth As Integer, bbHeight As Integer, adjMeasure As Int16
    'bbWidth = irdWidth : bbHeight = irdHeight - (tHeight + cImgHeight + (0.5 * ppi)) : boxX = 0 : boxY = tHeight + cImgHeight + (0.6 * ppi) : boxX1 = bbWidth - (0.375 * ppi) : boxY1 = boxY + bbHeight
    bbWidth = irdWidth : bbHeight = 0.5 * ppi : boxX = 0 : boxY = tHeight + cImgHeight + (0.45 * ppi) : boxX1 = bbWidth - (0.375 * ppi) : boxY1 = boxY + bbHeight

    adjMeasure = 10
    strFont = New Font("Courier New", micrChrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
    strText = "⑇"    '  Check Amount
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY - adjMeasure, boxX1, boxY1))

    strFont = New Font("MICR", micrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
    strText = CLng(cAmt).ToString("0000000000")     '  Check Amount
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxX1 = boxX + 2 * xGap
    boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1))

    strFont = New Font("Courier New", micrChrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
    strText = "  ⑇"    ' Check Amount
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString("00", strFont)
    boxX1 = boxX + 2 * xGap
    boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY - adjMeasure, boxX1, boxY1))

    ' Tran Code
    If CTranCode <> "" And cSerial = "" Then
        'strFont = New Font("Courier New", micrChrFontSize)
        'strText = "⑈" 'Check TranCode        
        'stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
        'boxX1 = boxX + 2 * xGap
        'boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
        'irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY - adjMeasure, boxX1, boxY1))

        strFont = New Font("MICR", micrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
        strText = CTranCode 'Check TranCode        
        stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString("0000", strFont)
        boxX1 = boxX + 2 * xGap
        boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
        irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1))

        'strFont = New Font("Courier New", micrChrFontSize)
        'strText = "⑈" 'Check TranCode        
        'stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
        'boxX1 = boxX + 2 * xGap
        'boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
        'irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY - adjMeasure, boxX1, boxY1))

    Else
        strText = "0000"
        stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
        boxX1 = boxX + 2 * xGap
        boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
        strText = "        "
        irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1))

    End If

    strFont = New Font("Courier New", micrChrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
    strText = "⑈" ' Check Account
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxX1 = boxX + 2 * xGap
    boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY - adjMeasure, boxX1, boxY1))

    strFont = New Font("MICR", micrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
    strText = cAccount.PadLeft((14 - cAccount.Length) * 3 + cAccount.Length)  ' Check Account Left Justinfied
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString("00000000000000", strFont)
    'textFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
    'textFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
    boxX1 = boxX + 2 * xGap
    boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1))

    strFont = New Font("Courier New", micrChrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
    strText = "⑆"           'Check RT        
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxX1 = boxX + 2 * xGap
    boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY - adjMeasure, boxX1, boxY1))

    strFont = New Font("MICR", micrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
    strText = cRT           'Check RT        
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxX1 = boxX + 2 * xGap
    boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1))

    strFont = New Font("Courier New", micrChrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
    strText = "⑆"          'Check RT        
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxX1 = boxX + 2 * xGap
    boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY - adjMeasure, boxX1, boxY1))

    strFont = New Font("MICR", micrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
    strText = "    4 "           'Check RT        
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    boxX1 = boxX + xGap
    boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1))

    If cSerial <> "" Then
        strFont = New Font("Courier New", micrChrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
        strText = "⑈"          'Check Serial     
        stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
        boxX1 = boxX + xGap
        boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
        irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY - adjMeasure, boxX1, boxY1))

        strFont = New Font("MICR", micrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
        strText = cSerial        'Check Serial     
        stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
        boxX1 = boxX + xGap
        boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
        irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1))

        strFont = New Font("Courier New", micrChrFontSize, FontStyle.Bold)
        strText = "⑈"           'Check Serial     
        stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
        boxX1 = boxX + 2 * xGap
        boxX = boxX1 - stringSize.Width
        irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY - adjMeasure, boxX1, boxY1))

    End If

    Return irdImg

End Function

'Create Rear IRD from check Rear image
Function convertRearIRD(chkImgBytes() As Byte) As Image
    Dim irdWidth As Integer, irdHeight As Integer, fontSize As Integer

    'Font sizes        
    fontSize = 9

    'Paper Sizes
    irdWidth = 8.5 * ppi      ' ( Assuming Letter paper size, 8.5 inch X 300 pixes/inch PPI)
    irdHeight = (11 / 3) * ppi    ' ( Assuming Letter paper size, 11 inch X 300 pixes/inch PPI) and each page would have 3 IRD pages
    Dim irdImg = New Bitmap(irdWidth, irdHeight)
    irdImg.SetResolution(ppi, ppi)
    Dim irdGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(irdImg)
    irdGraphics.Clear(Color.White)

    Dim strText As String, stringSize As New SizeF, strFont As Font, textFormat As New System.Drawing.StringFormat
    Dim chkImage As Image, cImgWidth As Integer, cImgHeight As Integer, boxX As Integer, boxY As Integer, boxX1 As Integer, boxY1 As Integer

    ''''       Rear Image                      
    cImgWidth = 5.75 * ppi : cImgHeight = 2.4 * ppi : boxX = 0 : boxY = 0.35 * ppi : boxX1 = cImgWidth : boxY1 = 0
    chkImage = Bitmap.FromStream(New IO.MemoryStream(chkImgBytes))
    If (chkImage.Width / chkImage.Height) * cImgHeight > cImgWidth Then cImgWidth = (chkImage.Width / chkImage.Height) * cImgHeight
    If (chkImage.Height / chkImage.Width) * cImgWidth > cImgHeight Then cImgHeight = (chkImage.Height / chkImage.Width) * cImgWidth
    irdGraphics.DrawImage(chkImage, boxX, boxY, cImgWidth, cImgHeight)

    ' Right Vertical Text        
    Dim rbWidth As Integer, rbHeight As Integer
    rbHeight = 2.25 * ppi : rbWidth = 2.25 * ppi : boxX = cImgWidth : boxY = 0.2 * ppi : boxX1 = irdWidth : boxY1 = boxY + rbHeight
    strFont = New Font("OCR-A Hanna", fontSize)
    textFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
    textFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center

    strText = hsSeq & vbNewLine & "*" & bankRt & "*  " & depDate
    stringSize = irdGraphics.MeasureString(strText, strFont)
    textFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical
    'irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX + (boxX1 - boxX - stringSize.Height / 2), boxY, boxX1, boxY1), textFormat)
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Point(boxX + stringSize.Width, boxY1 / 2 + boxY), textFormat)

    'Reprint on Image
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(0 + (boxX1 - boxX - stringSize.Width), boxY, boxX1 - boxX, boxY1), textFormat)
    'irdGraphics.ResetTransform()

    'Bottom Text        
    Dim bbWidth As Integer, bbHeight As Integer
    bbWidth = 2.25 * ppi : bbHeight = 0.2 * ppi : boxX = cImgWidth : boxY = 0.15 * ppi + boxY1 : boxX1 = boxX1 : boxY1 = boxY + bbHeight
    fontSize = 5
    strFont = New Font("OCR-A Hanna", fontSize, FontStyle.Bold)

    strText = "↓ Do not endorse or write below this line. ↓"
    irdGraphics.DrawString(strText, strFont, Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(boxX, boxY, boxX1, boxY1))
    irdGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, New Point(boxX, boxY1), New Point(irdWidth, boxY1))

    Return irdImg

End Function
```